# Combinable filters

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I have an initial pool of subjects, then I need to apply a set of general criteria to retain a smaller subset (SS1) of subjects. Then I need to divide this smaller subset (SS1) into yet finer subsets (SS1-A, SS1-B and the rest). A specific set of criteria will be applied to SS1 to obtain the SS1-A, while another set of specific criteria will be applied to obtain the SS1-B, and the rest will be discarded. The set of criteria/filter will need to be flexible, I would like to add, remove, or combine filters for testing and development, as well as for further clients' requests.

I created a small structure code below to help me understand and test the implementation of template method and filter methods. I use a list and some filter instead of actual subject pool, but the idea is similar that the list items can be seen as subjects with different attributes.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class DataProcessing(ABC):
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def data_processing_steps(self):
        self.remove_duplicate()
        self.general_filtering()
        self.subject_specific_filtering()
        self.return_list()

    def remove_duplicate(self):
        self.my_list = set(list(self.my_list))

    @abstractmethod
    def general_filtering(self): pass

    def subject_specific_filtering(self): pass

    def return_list(self):
        return self.my_list

class DataProcessing_Project1(DataProcessing):
    def general_filtering(self):
        maxfilter_obj = MaxFilter()
        minfilter_obj = MinFilter()
        CombinedFilter_obj = CombinedFilter(maxfilter_obj, minfilter_obj)
        self.my_list = CombinedFilter_obj.filter(self.my_list)

class DataProcessing_Project1_SubjectA(DataProcessing_Project1):
    def subject_specific_filtering(self):
        twentythreefilter_obj = TwentyThreeFilter()
        self.my_list = twentythreefilter_obj.filter(self.my_list)

class DataProcessing_Project1_SubjectB(DataProcessing_Project1): pass

class Criteria():
    @abstractmethod
    def filter(self, request):
        raise NotImplementedError('Should have implemented this.')

class CombinedFilter(Criteria):
    def __init__(self, filter1, filter2):
        self.filter1 = filter1
        self.filter2 = filter2

    def filter(self, this_list):
        filteredList1 = self.filter1.filter(this_list)
        filteredList2 = self.filter2.filter(filteredList1)
        return filteredList2

class MaxFilter(Criteria):
    def __init__(self, max_val=100):
        self.max_val = max_val

    def filter(self, this_list):
        filteredList = []
        for item in this_list:
            if item <= self.max_val:
                filteredList.append(item)
        return filteredList

class MinFilter(Criteria):
    def __init__(self, min_val=10):
        self.min_val = min_val

    def filter(self, this_list):
        filteredList = []
        for item in this_list:
            if item >= self.min_val:
                filteredList.append(item)
        return filteredList

class TwentyThreeFilter(Criteria):
    def __init__(self): pass

    def filter(self, this_list):
        filteredList = []
        for item in this_list:
            if item != 23:
                filteredList.append(item)
        return filteredList 


this_list = [1, 2, 23, 4, 34, 456, 234, 23, 3457, 5, 2]

ob = MaxFilter()
this_list2 = ob.filter(this_list)
print(this_list2)

ob2 = MinFilter()
this_list3 = ob2.filter(this_list2)
print(this_list3)

ob3 = CombinedFilter(ob, ob2)
this_list4 = ob3.filter(this_list)
print(this_list4)

ob4 = DataProcessing_Project1(my_list=this_list)
ob4.data_processing_steps()
print(ob4.return_list())

ob5 = DataProcessing_Project1_SubjectA(my_list=this_list)
ob5.data_processing_steps()
print(ob5.return_list())

# Error
twentythreefilter_obj = TwentyThreeFilter()
ob6 = CombinedFilter(ob, ob2, twentythreefilter_obj)
this_list4 = ob3.filter(this_list)
print(this_list4)
```

I am fairly new to design pattern, I wonder if this is implemented correctly, and if there are areas that can be improved?

Also for `ob6`, I would like to add another filter as a parameter for `combinedFilter()`, but I am not sure how to set the `__init__` and `filter()` within the `ComninedFilter` class so that it can accommodate the addition of any number of new filters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your approach is suitable for a language like Java.  But in Python?  [Stop writing classes!](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html)  This is especially true for your task, where much of the code consists of do-nothing placeholders (in **bold** below) just to allow functionality to be implemented by subclasses.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class DataProcessing(ABC):
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def data_processing_steps(self):
        self.remove_duplicate()
        self.general_filtering()
        self.subject_specific_filtering()
        self.return_list()

    def remove_duplicate(self):
        self.my_list = set(list(self.my_list))

    @abstractmethod
    def general_filtering(self): pass

    def subject_specific_filtering(self): pass

    def return_list(self):
        return self.my_list

class DataProcessing_Project1(DataProcessing):
    def general_filtering(self):
        maxfilter_obj = MaxFilter()
        minfilter_obj = MinFilter()
        CombinedFilter_obj = CombinedFilter(maxfilter_obj, minfilter_obj)
        self.my_list = CombinedFilter_obj.filter(self.my_list)

class DataProcessing_Project1_SubjectA(DataProcessing_Project1):
    def subject_specific_filtering(self):
        twentythreefilter_obj = TwentyThreeFilter()
        self.my_list = twentythreefilter_obj.filter(self.my_list)

class DataProcessing_Project1_SubjectB(DataProcessing_Project1): pass
```

Furthermore, it's unnatural to have `my_list` be part of the state of the `DataProcessing` instance, and it's especially awkward to have to retrieve the result by calling `.return_list()`.

Note that in

> ```
> def remove_duplicate(self):
>     self.my_list = set(list(self.my_list))
> ```

… `my_list` temporarily becomes a `set` rather than a `list`.  You should have written `self.my_list = list(set(self.my_list))` instead.

### Suggested solution

This task is more naturally suited to functional programming.  Each filter can be a function that accepts an iterable and returns an iterable.  You can then easily combine filters through [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29).

As a bonus, you can take advantage of **default parameter values** in Python to supply generic processing steps.  Then, just **use `None` to indicate that an absent processing step**.

```
######################################################################
# Primitive filters
######################################################################
def deduplicator():
    return lambda iterable: list(set(iterable))

def at_least(threshold=10):
    return lambda iterable: [n for n in iterable if n >= threshold]

def at_most(threshold=100):
    return lambda iterable: [n for n in iterable if n <= threshold]

def is_not(bad_value):
    return lambda iterable: [n for n in iterable if n != bad_value]

######################################################################
# Higher-order filters
######################################################################
def compose(*filters):
    def composed(iterable):
        for f in filters:
            if f is not None:
                iterable = f(iterable)
        return iterable
    return composed

def data_processing(
        deduplicate=deduplicator(),
        general=compose(at_least(), at_most()),
        specific=None,
    ):
    return compose(deduplicate, general, specific)

######################################################################
# Demonstration
######################################################################
this_list = [1, 2, 23, 4, 34, 456, 234, 23, 3457, 5, 2]

ob = at_most()
this_list2 = ob(this_list)
print(this_list2)       # [1, 2, 23, 4, 34, 23, 5, 2]

ob2 = at_least()
this_list3 = ob2(this_list2)
print(this_list3)       # [23, 34, 23]

ob3 = compose(ob, ob2)
this_list4 = ob3(this_list)
print(this_list4)       # [23, 34, 23]

ob4 = data_processing()
print(ob4(this_list))   # [34, 23]

ob5 = data_processing(specific=is_not(23))
print(ob5(this_list))   # [34]

ob6 = compose(ob, ob2, is_not(23))
print(ob6(this_list))   # [34]
```

Comment: Is your don't write class comment pointing to my boilerplate code above, or in general? I see that many design patterns (ie abstract factory - https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory/python/1) use a lot of empty classes (with pass) as interface, does it mean refactoring  code with these design patterns are generally bad? My code above was a subsequent question that I tried following `Girish`'s comments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858784/how-to-apply-template-method-pattern-in-python-data-science-process-while-not-kn/55860141#55860141)

Comment: Also, my above code is basically a test code. My data will be as Pandas df which I will be using different var column as attributes to filter subjects. Would the iterable suggestion still apply? If so, do I treat each row/subject as an iterable?

Comment: A lot of "design patterns" are just workarounds for limitations of straitjacket OOP languages like Java or C++. Watch the video.

Comment: We encourage users to post real code for review, because we can't review what you had in mind but decided not to show. (See [ask].) If you have another question, then post it as a separate follow-up question.

Comment: I've been on SE for 7 years and it's never occurred to me to put code in a `<pre>` so you can bold important sections. +1 Fantastic approach! I'm 100% stealing this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you would benefit from viewing your processing steps and criteria as *filters* that operate on [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Suppose you have a sequence, like a `set` or a `list` or a `tuple`. You could iterate over that sequence like so:

```
for item in sequence:
    pass
```

Now suppose you use the [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=iter%20built#iter) built-in function to create an iterator, instead. Now you can pass around that iterator, and even extract values from it:

```
it = iter(sequence)
first_item = next(it)
print_remaining_items(it)
```

Finally, suppose you take advantage of [generator functions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) and avoid collecting and returning entire lists. You can iterate over the elements of an iterable, inspect the individual values, and yield the ones you choose:

```
def generator(it):
    for item in it:
        if choose(item):
            yield item
```

This allows you to process one iterable, and iterate over the results of your function, which makes it another iterable.

Thus, you can build a "stack" of iterables, with your initial sequence (or perhaps just an iterable) at the bottom, and some generator function at each higher level:

```
ibl = sequence
st1 = generator(ibl)
st2 = generator(st1)
st3 = generator(st2)

for item in st3:
    print(item)  # Will print chosen items from sequence
```

So how would this work in practice?

Let's start with a simple use case: you have an iterable, and you wish to filter it using one or more simple conditionals.

```
class FilteredData:
    def __init__(self, ibl):
        self.iterable = ibl
        self.condition = self.yes

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.ibl:
            if self.condition(item):
                yield item

    def yes(self, item):
        return True

obj = FilteredData([1,2,3,4])

for item in obj:
    print(item)   # 1, 2, 3, 4

obj.condition = lambda item: item % 2 == 0

for item in obj:
    print(item)  # 2, 4
```

How can we combine multiple conditions? By "stacking" objects. Wrap one iterable item inside another, and you "compose" the filters:

```
obj = FilteredData([1,2,3,4])
obj.condition = lambda item: item % 2 == 0
obj2 = FilteredData(obj)
obj2.condition = lambda item: item < 3

for item in obj2:
    print(item)  # 2
```

Obviously, you can make things more complex. I'd suggest that you not do that until you establish a clear need.

For example, you could pass in the lambda as part of the constructor. Or subclass FilteredData.

Another example, you could "slurp" up the entire input as part of your `__iter__` method in order to compute some aggregate value (like min, max, or average) then yield the values one at a time. It's painful since it consumes O(N) memory instead of just O(1), but sometimes it's necessary. That would require a subclass, or a more complex class.